# QGIS Processing modeler not showing toolbar

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler, toolbar

I've just installed QGIS recently (3.10.10 with GRASS 7.8.3) on a new computer. Previously, I used the same version and there's a toolbar in the Processing Modeler (to save and run model). But now, I cannot see it anymore. Why is it?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should right-click on a place somewhere near Variable Window (in your screenshot) and a window appears like in the image below and there select `Navigation`. Then the toolbar should appear again

[image]